# Strange artifact when updating Pivot title in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a XAML page with just a `Pivot` with binded ItemSource and the following template (changing just the header for simpilcity)

```
<phone:Pivot
    Margin="0,108,0,0"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Services}">
    <phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

The ItemSource (Services) is an `ObservableCollection` of a simple data type with just a `Title` property implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`. When I change the `Title` of any item, the `Pivot` header is rendered very strangely:

[image]

Here is a complete simplified solution to reproduce the problem: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73642/pivotproblem.zip

Is this a `Pivot` bug?

Comment: Indeed a bug... I had the same problem and I end up in forcing to reaload whole data context of the Pivot. Since I was using MVVM I just created new instance of the items collection and raised property changed for that.

Comment: Yes, this seems to work (also using MVVM). Make it an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed a bug... I had the same problem and I end up in forcing to reload whole DataContext of the Pivot.

Since I was using MVVM I just created new instance of the items collection and raised property changed for that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `TextBlock's` `Width` is not updated after `Title` changes. You can check it by defining your `TextBlock` like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Width="400" />
```

Hence it's not updated, two Titles overlap each other.

Comment: Yes, this stops the labels from overlapping. But this is not a solution, setting the width makes the labels look strange and not very much like a pivot.

Comment: @IgorKulman Yep, you are right that this is not a solution - it says where the problem lies. Maybe you can try to update TextBlock, or Bind its Width to property TitleWidth - and invoke property changed for it, then put some ligic to TitleWidth's getter.